# Интерактивное масштабируемое изображение на движке Google

Tags: google-maps-api, google-app-engine

Как использовать движок гугл для создания масштабируемого изображения с интерактивными элементами?

Вот [пример](http://flybase.org/maps/chromosomes/maps.html), который хотелось бы повторить под свои нужды.

Мануала и примеров, увы не нашёл, кругом всё ссылки и api просто по импорту гугловских карт на свой сайт.

Comment: Я думаю это можно реализовать на jquery, да еще и в более красивом и функциональном варианте)

Comment: я тоже так думаю, ну а примеры того о чём вы говорите могли бы скинуть? просто совсем не хочется на это тратить много времени, а тут по виду, эта "карта" создана в каком-то редакторе гугловском, мб весьма удобном, хотелось бы найти.

Answer (score 1):

Это делается очень легко и непринуждённо. Есть сервис [Gmap Uploader](http://gmapuploader.com/) (существует уже давно) который позволяет делать то что вы хотите. А [вот тут](http://webmap-blog.ru/google-maps/create-your-own-maps-using-the-api-google-maps) описано как перенести это добро на собственный сервер.